# Assignment inside generic parameter <T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T>

Tags: typescript

Having come across the following code:

```
type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T>
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain what's `keyof T = keyof T`?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13487

Comment: @ChrisYungmann The handbook link to mapped types doesn't seem relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that function takes one required type parameter T, and an optional type parameter Keys that extends the subset of the indices of T and defaults to those indices.

The assignment is the default value for that second, optional type parameter.

To put it slightly differently, that second type parameter says "I take a type that is the extension of the keys of T, and if you don't pass an explicit type parameter then it defaults to just the keys of T".

Comment: "superset" should be changed to "subset".  EDIT: "extends the set" might be true or false depending on what you mean.  `"foo" extends ("foo" | "bar")` is true, `("foo" | "bar") extends "foo"` is false.

Comment: @jcalz good catch, fixed. Probably should have said the union of the public props anyway.